# No notification on passbook update

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, passbook, wallet

The project I work on is using a website and a PWA and not native apps. Because of this, I turned to Apple Wallet to notify my users with push notifications.

I used [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/adding_a_web_service_to_update_passes) from Apple documentation to help me create passes and register them for updates and push notifications.

To notify a user, the key 'change_message' has to be present in at least one of the fields of the updated Passbook

The problem I have is that event though the passbook is getting updated, notifications don't always appear. (Most of the time they don't)

They do definitly work in some cases, but I can't tell why. For instance, when I turn my phone off then turn it back on, I do receive notifications.

After a couple of hours, I go back to getting updates but no notifications.

Has someone encountered a similar problem ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happens to me, and after check iPhone logs with this command in linux:

```
idevicesyslog | grep PassKitCore
```

or use log unfiltered

```
idevicesyslog
```

Found a message about threshold limits inside device... The problem is this threshold is not documented or anybody talking about that but the message log is very explicit about this limit.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer... Never saw mention of this limit in the documentation either.

Do you know what the limit is ? 
Do you also know if I can check iPhone logs on Windows ? I don't have an iMac myself and I am using Windows

I believed that I could notify users this way but if the limit is so low it is pointless to even try to notify them... Especially since people tend to never turn their phones off...